# How do i slide the actionbar along with the pane in SlidingPane layout?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, slidingpanelayout

I have implemented slidingpane layout in my first android application, but when I slide the menu the actionbar still remains static  and I wanted to implement something like Google+ app does 
[image]

There was a similar questions posted in Stack Overflow where people suggested to import Sliding menu library from github, but in my case I have Implemented the SlidingPane layout imported from android support library (android.support.v4).. Is there a way of achieving it? If so please share your knowledge and help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a custom library to do this. "Sliding menu library from github" will be a good choice for it. For example implementation of slidingpane check out Google Hangouts(pic here https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqTvr.png)